flutter - just audio package is not working with Ios when Api returns partial content with status code 206
I'm working on a flutter music app with just-audio package and it's working fine on Android, but when I play audios (partial content 206 especially) on Ios, It's not working probably. I can't play songs or get the right duration on Ios.
This is the song Handler file code:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../app_export.dart';

class SongHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with QueueHandler, SeekHandler {
  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  final playlist =
      ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [], useLazyPreparation: true);

  SongHandler() {
    initializeAudioSession();
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Audio Session Settings

  Future<void> initializeAudioSession() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    try {
      await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.music());
      session.interruptionEventStream.listen((event) async {
        if (event.begin) {
          switch (event.type) {
            case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
              await audioPlayer.setVolume(0.5);
              break;
            case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
            case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
              await audioPlayer.pause();
              break;
          }
        } else {
          switch (event.type) {
            case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
              await audioPlayer.setVolume(1);
              break;
            case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
              await audioPlayer.play();
              break;
            case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint('Error initializing audio session: $stackTrace');
    }
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Initial Audio Sources

  UriAudioSource createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    return AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url'] as String),
        tag: mediaItem);
  }

  List<UriAudioSource> createAudioSources(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) {
    return mediaItems
        .map(
          (item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.extras!['url'] as String),
              tag: item,
              headers: {}),
        )
        .toList();
  }

//etc...

> Future<void> setNewPlaylist(List<MediaItem> mediaItems, int index) async {
    if (!Platform.isAndroid && audioPlayer.playing) {
      await audioPlayer.stop();
    }
    var getCount = queue.value.length;
    await playlist.removeRange(0, getCount);
    final audioSource = createAudioSources(mediaItems);
    await playlist.addAll(audioSource);
    final newQueue = queue.value..addAll(mediaItems);
    queue.add(newQueue);

    try {
      audioPlayer.setAudioSource(playlist,
          initialIndex: index, initialPosition: Duration.zero);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
  }


I tried to call setNewPlaylist when I click on a song in the list and this was the error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: (-1) unknown error
I build my SongBloc and listeners to update the duration and mediaItem Object:

class SongBloc extends Bloc<SongEvent, SongState> {
  final NetworkInfo _networkInfo;
  final SongHandler songHandler;

  SongBloc(this._networkInfo, this.songHandler)
      : super(const SongState().copyWith(
            songsStatus: SongsStatus.initial,
            isPlaying: [],
            mediaItems: [],
            selectedSongId: "")) {
    // Set up listeners
    _initializeListeners();

    on<SelectSong>(onSelectSong);
    on<PlaySong>(onPlaySong);
    on<PauseSong>(onPauseSong);
    on<SkipToNextSong>(onSkipToNextSong);
    on<SkipToPreviousSong>(onSkipToPreviousSong);
  }

  //create listen functions
  void _initializeListeners() {
    songHandler.audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((duration) {
      _handleDurationChange(duration);
    });

    songHandler.audioPlayer.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      _handleCurrentSongIndexChange(index);
    });

    songHandler.audioPlayer.sequenceStateStream.listen((sequenceState) {
      _handleSequenceStateChange(sequenceState);
    });

    songHandler.audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      _handlePlaybackEvent(event);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _handleDurationChange(Duration? duration) async {
    var index = songHandler.audioPlayer.currentIndex;
    final newQueue = state.mediaItems;
    if (index == null || newQueue!.isEmpty || newQueue.length < index) {
      return;
    }
    if (songHandler.audioPlayer.shuffleModeEnabled) {
      index = songHandler.audioPlayer.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
    }
    final oldMediaItem = newQueue[index];

    //duration = await songHandler.fetchAudioDuration(oldMediaItem.extras!['url'] as String);

    final newMediaItem = oldMediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
    newQueue[index] = newMediaItem;

    emit(state.copyWith(songDuration: duration, mediaItem: newMediaItem));
  }

  Future<void> _handleCurrentSongIndexChange(int? index) async {
    final pPlaylist = state.mediaItems;
    if (index == null || pPlaylist!.isEmpty) return;
    if (songHandler.audioPlayer.shuffleModeEnabled) {
      index = songHandler.audioPlayer.shuffleIndices!.indexOf(index);
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedIndexSong: index,
        selectedSongId: pPlaylist[index].id,
        mediaItem: pPlaylist[index]));

    final PaletteGenerator paletteGenerator =
        await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
      NetworkImage(
          "${Config.imageBaseUrl}${state.songsListEntity![index].photoUrl}"),
      size: const Size(200, 200),
      maximumColorCount: 20,
    );

    final Color dominantColor =
        paletteGenerator.darkMutedColor?.color ?? AppColor.primaryColor;

    emit(state.copyWith(
      backgroundColor: dominantColor,
    ));
  }

  void _handleSequenceStateChange(SequenceState? sequenceState) {
    final sequence = sequenceState?.effectiveSequence;
    if (sequence == null || sequence.isEmpty) return;
    final items = sequence.map((source) => source.tag as MediaItem).toList();
    emit(state.copyWith(mediaItems: items));
  }

  void _handlePlaybackEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    final playing = songHandler.audioPlayer.playing;
    songHandler.playbackState.add(
      songHandler.playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.stop,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],
        systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.seek,
          MediaAction.seekForward,
          MediaAction.seekBackward,
        },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[songHandler.audioPlayer.processingState]!,
        repeatMode: const {
          LoopMode.off: AudioServiceRepeatMode.none,
          LoopMode.one: AudioServiceRepeatMode.one,
          LoopMode.all: AudioServiceRepeatMode.all,
        }[songHandler.audioPlayer.loopMode]!,
        shuffleMode: songHandler.audioPlayer.shuffleModeEnabled
            ? AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
            : AudioServiceShuffleMode.none,
        playing: playing,
        updatePosition: songHandler.audioPlayer.position,
        bufferedPosition: songHandler.audioPlayer.bufferedPosition,
        speed: songHandler.audioPlayer.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex ?? 0,
      ),
    );

    List<bool> isPlaying = [];
    isPlaying.addAll(state.isPlaying!);
    if (state.selectedIndexSong != null && isPlaying.isNotEmpty) {
      if (playing) {
        isPlaying[state.selectedIndexSong!] = true;
      } else {
        isPlaying[state.selectedIndexSong!] = false;
      }
      emit(state.copyWith(
        isPlaying: isPlaying,
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> onSelectSong(SelectSong event, Emitter<SongState> emit) async {
    try {
      final mediaItems =
          event.songs.map(MediaConverter.mediaToMediaItem).toList();

      final MediaItem mediaItem = mediaItems[event.index];

      emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedSongId: mediaItem.id,
        selectedIndexSong: event.index,
      ));

      if (MediaConverter.areMediaItemsEqual(state.mediaItems!, mediaItems)) {
        await songHandler.skipToQueueItem(event.index);
      } else {
        await songHandler.setNewPlaylist(mediaItems, event.index);
        List<bool> isPlaying = [];
        isPlaying = List.filled(event.songs.length, false);
        emit(state.copyWith(
          isPlaying: isPlaying,
        ));
      }

      final PaletteGenerator paletteGenerator =
          await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
        NetworkImage(
            "${Config.imageBaseUrl}${event.songs[event.index].photoUrl}"),
        size: const Size(200, 200),
        maximumColorCount: 20,
      );

      final Color dominantColor =
          paletteGenerator.darkMutedColor?.color ?? Colors.black;

      emit(state.copyWith(
        backgroundColor: dominantColor,
      ));

      songHandler.play();

      emit(state.copyWith(
        songsListEntity: event.songs,
        currentSong: event.songs[event.index],
        mediaItem: mediaItem,
        mediaItems: mediaItems,
        songsStatus: SongsStatus.selectSong,
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        songsStatus: SongsStatus.error,
        error: const PlaybackFailure('Failed to select song', ""),
      ));
    }
  }

}

I think the problem in response headers from the server cause the player of ios can't read chunks of audio probably, it returns like this:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1000002
Content-Range: bytes 965921-1965921/11279288
Content-Type: audio/mpeg3
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2024 08:05:29 GMT
Server: nginx/1.22.0
X-Powered-By: Express
I tried to add header "Range" in get request of the audio like this:
List<UriAudioSource> createAudioSources(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) {
    return mediaItems
        .map(
          (item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.extras!['url'] as String),
              tag: item,
              headers: {
                "Range": "",
              }),
        )
        .toList();
  }

and the only way it works when I added it with an empty value, the audio was working on Ios but with duration zero and wrong listeners.
I can't seek or streaming in the audio in song progress.
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:audio_video_progress_bar/audio_video_progress_bar.dart';
import '../../../../core/app_export.dart';
import '../bloc/song_bloc.dart';

class SongProgress extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration? totalDuration;
  final Color? color;

  const SongProgress({
    super.key,
    this.totalDuration,
    this.color,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Duration>(
      stream: AudioService.position,
      builder: (context, positionSnapshot) {
        Duration? position = positionSnapshot.data;
        return ProgressBar(
          progress: position ?? Duration.zero,
          buffered: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          total: totalDuration ?? Duration.zero,
          onSeek: (position) {
            BlocProvider.of<SongBloc>(context).songHandler.seek(position);
          },
          progressBarColor: color,
          baseBarColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
          bufferedBarColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
          thumbColor: Colors.white,
          barHeight: 3.h,
          thumbRadius: 5.h,
          timeLabelTextStyle: Styles.textStyle14.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


what I do to configure everything in ios audio player?
